# Websphere Shared Log Writer(com.ibm.ejs.ras.SharedLogWriter)

Tags: websphere

I am experiencing very low speed on production environment. I am analyzing the system, and the reason I have found is that all the threads in the system are waiting to access "Shared Log Writer" in websphere environment. What can be the possible reason for this.

what is Websphere Shared Log Writer(com.ibm.ejs.ras.SharedLogWriter), does it manage the log written in the websphere. And why it is blocking the application. My application is also using log4j log and most of the log is written in log4j log files, then if there is some error because of writing on disk, then it should be in the log4j process not in Websphere share log writer.

What are the possible reasons for this. Am I using websphere log file too much for the reporting errors. Please provide me your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You might be logging too much data into the log, but it might be also a delay introduced by synchronization of i/o operations between different processes. As the name suggests, it is a shared log writer. When using WAS ND, multiple processes of the same node (profile) write to the same file, hence the need to synchronize.

In administrative terminology this file is referred as "service log" and is located in ${LOG_ROOT}/activity.log by default.

In most of the cases you don't really need that log and you can disable it without serious consequences.

Service log can be disabled in the following way: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ttrb_cfgsvclog.html

You can do it using wsadmin script globally for your cell.

In wsadmin/jython:

```py
for sl in AdminConfig.getid('/ServiceLog:/').splitlines():
    AdminConfig.modify(sl, [['enabled', 'false']])
AdminConfig.save()
```

***Advertisement mode***

I wouldn't be myself if I didn't use this opportunity to advertise [WDR](http://wdr.github.io/WDR/) library, which greatly improves readability and maintainability of WebSphere scripts. So, with [WDR](http://wdr.github.io/WDR/) the script would look as follows:

```py
for sl in getid('/ServiceLog:/'):
    sl.enabled = 0
save()
sync()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me what information is logged in Activity.log by websphere and is it high too high & slowing down my system. System capacity for production is good. It is slowing down only on high volumes like 500 users at a time etc. There are other logs like SystemOut.log and SystemErr.log. Are they not part of the same Websphere Shared Log Writer. Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Also one information to share that all these logs are not versioned, like all the log is logged in one file. Whereas for my log4j log files, I am versioning each hour. After every hour a new file is created. What impact can this have, if the file size is getting bigger.

Comment: The activity.log is a binary file. You need to use specialized tools to view it. For WAS 8.5 you can use showlog.<sh|bat> command, for other versions you'll need use "Log and Trace Analyzer" from Application Server Toolkit. More info on viewing: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/ttrb_viewsvclog.html

Comment: Regarding your question about log rotation: you have similar options for SystemOut/SystemErr logs. Log rotation can be time-based or size-based: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/utrb_jvmlogs.html